# Is this function the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function here that I'm not sure if it is the Gamma function, or perhaps the Gamma function by some periodic function. Or if I am just making a series of mistakes.

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(z+n)} - \frac{1}{e} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)}$$

We can show, really fast:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
zf(z) &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z (-1)^n}{n!(z+n)} - \frac{1}{e} - \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n)}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{(-1)^n z}{n!(z+n)} - \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}) - \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n)}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} n}{n!(z+n)} - \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n)}\\
&=& f(z+1)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

However, the residues at the poles come out to zero and $f(1)=0$ as well, unlike the Gamma function. Is it not the Gamma function or am I miscalculating something..? Because I think it should be the Gamma function, just not certain.

Any help on clarifying what this function may or may not be, or if you've seen this expression somewhere before, that would be amazing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The functional equation $zf(z) = f(z+1)$ together with the fact that it has no poles (the residue is $0$, and the potential poles cannot have order greater than $1$) implies $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: The Bohr-Mollerup characterizes the Gamma function, and one of the first things to check (at least imo) is that $\;f(1)=1\;$ , which according to what you wrote isn't fulfilled, thus $\;f\neq\Gamma\;$ ...

Comment: Both your terms are equal to $\Gamma(z)-\Gamma(z,1)$, thus $f(z)=0$, for all $z\in\mathbb C^*$.